# Intellisense on object using special comments

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, intellisense, jsdoc

In Sublime or VS Code you can define a special comment ([DocBlockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs) or [JSDocs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments) as example) that Intellisense will recognize en give you smart tooltip functionality.

I have a function which takes an options parameter. This is an object and can have several properties that could contain functions, strings, ints etc. An example would be:

```
function foo(options){
    options = options || {};

    if(options.foo){
        console.log(options.foo);
    }
    if(options.bar) {
        console.log(options.bar());
    }
}
foo({foo: 'foo', bar: function(){return 'bar';}});
```

I could add a DocBlockr comment, but that would only yield a tooltip that shows it needs an object.

Is it possible to make some sort of definition of that options object, so it would popup using intellisense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sublime Text 3, you can use my [JavaScript Enhancement](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/JavaScriptEnhancements) plugin (you could find it also on **Package Control**) that will turn it into a JavaScript IDE like (It uses [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) under the hood). In your case, using [Flow type annotations](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/), you could use this code to get what you want:

```
//@flow

function foo(options /*: { foo: string, bar: function} */){
    options = options || {};

    if(options.foo){
        console.log(options.foo);
    }    
    if(options.bar) {
        console.log(options.bar());
    }
}

foo()
```

So, on the Sublime Text 3 editor, you will get something like this:
[image]

also on multiple lines (`/* :` need to be on the same line of the parameter):

[image]

Also, the plugin offers not only a smart javascript autocomplete but also a lot of features about creating, developing and managing javascript projects (real-time errors, code refactoring, etc.).

Comment: This looks amazing! However, is there a way to have the definitions above the function using multiple lines? My options objects can be quite large

Comment: yeah! I have updated my answer with a new screenshot. You can see all the possible ways on the Flow site.

Comment: Woah! Thanks so much! I'll definitly will give this a shot. Have you any plans for a VS Code port?

Comment: There is already this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) that enables the support for Flow in VS Code. My main goal is to offers JavaScript IDE-like features for Sublime Text 3 because it is very fast (it is written in C++ if I'm right) compared to other editors (Atom and VSCode are based on Electron), but it lacks a lot of features, so this is why I'm focusing on Sublime Text 3 :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, awesome! Keep it up :)